# MySQL sub-lines numbering

Tags: mysql, lines

MySQL sub-lines numbering (MySQL only, without PHP ...)

EX : The line number of a invoces

table bill  whith all lines of all invoces

```
*----------*--------*-------*------*--------*
* bill_num *  item  * price * qte  * sl_num *
*----------*--------*-------*------*--------*
*       10 * js1eee * 12.10 *    3 *        *
*       10 * ft78eg * 15.10 *    7 *        *
*       10 * ite489 * 10.10 *    5 *        *
*       10 * ite78b * 24.10 *    6 *        *
*       11 * it785b * 39.10 *    7 *        *
*       11 * it7889 * 78.10 *    9 *        *
*       11 * it7899 * 41.10 *    7 *        *
*       12 * ite489 * 41.10 *    8 *        *
*       12 * ite78b * 33.10 *    7 *        *
```

After query

```
*----------*--------*-------*------*--------*
* bill_num *  item  * price * qte  * sl_num *
*----------*--------*-------*------*--------*
*       10 * js1eee * 12.10 *    3 *      1 *
*       10 * ft78eg * 15.10 *    7 *      2 *
*       10 * ite489 * 10.10 *    5 *      3 *
*       10 * ite78b * 24.10 *    6 *      4 *
*       11 * it785b * 39.10 *    7 *      1 *
*       11 * it7889 * 78.10 *    9 *      2 *
*       11 * it7899 * 41.10 *    7 *      3 *
*       12 * ite489 * 41.10 *    8 *      1 *
```

I have not found a solution on the internet
I developed this trick

```
UPDATE bill AS a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT bill_num  FROM bill
    GROUP BY bill_num
) AS b ON b.bill_num=a.bill_num 

SET sl_num = @ordre := IF(a.bill_num= @bill_num_mem, @ordre+1, ( @bill_num_mem:=b.bill_num) OR @ordre:=1)
WHERE  b.bill_num=a.bill_num
```

In my case it works, but with other MySQL version, string instead of intergers... ?. 
I think there is less complicated and more reliable

Thank to Barmar, it's work, a line in less. May be simpler solution around variables ?

```
UPDATE bill AS a
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT bill_num FROM bill ORDER BY bill_num
) AS b ON b.bill_num=a.bill_num 

SET sl_num = @ordre := IF(a.bill_num= @bill_num_mem, @ordre+1, ( @bill_num_mem:=b.bill_num) OR @ordre:=1)
WHERE  b.bill_num=a.bill_num
```

Comment: I think that's about the best way to do it. You can simplify the subquery to `(SELECT DISTINCT bill_num FROM bill ORDER BY bill_num)`